# Игнорирование не существующей переменной python

Tags: python

```
def func():
   a = 1
   b = a+c
   print(b)
func()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если **c** не существует, то просто не прибавлять её?

Comment: Может сделать так: если с равно нулю, то не прибавлять?

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать двумя путями:

1. объявить заранее `c = None` и добавить проверку `if c is not None`
2. По вашему контексту можно задать заранее для переменной значение `c = 0` и если нет другого переопределения переменной, то и сложение ничего не изменит.

Есть и более костыльный выход через рефлексию. Вот был [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вы решаете не ту проблему. Функция в принципе не должна оперировать переменными, которые в неё не были переданы явным образом как параметры. Ну, если это не метод класса. В обоих случаях проблема решается либо параметром функции со значением по умолчанию 0, либо если это класс, то сразу инициализировать переменную класса нулём прямо при создании класса.

А вот такое, что простая функция (не метод класса) оперирует какими-то непонятными внешними переменными, взявшимися неизвестно откуда - такого не должно быть, это рано или поздно непонятные глюки обеспечены. Так код не надо писать.

Answer (score 1):

*если c не существует, то просто не прибавлять её?*

```
def func():
    a = 1
    try:
        b = a+c
    except NameError:
        b = a
    print(b)
func()
```